# Speed up for loop in R

Tags: r

I have following data.frame and dictionaries with pos/negWords:

```
sent <- data.frame(words = c("just right size and i love this notebook", "benefits great laptop",
                         "wouldnt bad notebook", "very good quality", "orgtop",
                         "great improvement", "notebook is not good but i love batterytop"), user = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7),
               stringsAsFactors=F)

posWords <- c("great","improvement","love","great improvement","very good","good","right","very","benefits",
          "extra","benefit","top","extraordinarily","extraordinary","super","benefits super")
negWords <- c("hate","bad","not good","horrible")
```

And the following function, which is matching words in each sentence with pos/negWords from dictionaries and compute sentiment value according frequency of occurance - but it is exact match.

```
# descending order for words length (prepare data for function below)
wordsDF <- data.frame(words = posWords, value = 1,stringsAsFactors=F)
wordsDF <- rbind(wordsDF,data.frame(words = negWords, value = -1))
wordsDF$lengths <- unlist(lapply(wordsDF$words, nchar))
wordsDF <- wordsDF[order(-wordsDF[,3]),]
rownames(wordsDF) <- NULL

scoreSentence <- function(sentence){
   score <- 0
   for(x in 1:nrow(wordsDF)){
      match <- paste("\\<",wordsDF[x,1],'\\>', sep="") # matching exact words
      count <- length(grep(match,sentence)) # count them
      if(count){
         score <- score + (count * wordsDF[x,2]) # compute score (count * sentValue)
         sentence <- gsub(paste0('\\s*\\b', wordsDF[x,1], '\\b\\s*', collapse='|'), '', sentence) # remove words which were matched
       } score
}
```

which generate desired output with calling:

```
SentimentScore <- unlist(lapply(sent$words, scoreSentence))
bbb <- cbind(sent, SentimentScore)
```

This resulted into mentioned desired output:

```
                                       words user SentimentScore
1   just right size and i love this notebook    1              2
2                      benefits great laptop    2              2
3                       wouldnt bad notebook    3             -1
4                          very good quality    4              1
5                                     orgtop    5              0
6                          great improvement    6              1
7 notebook is not good but i love batterytop    7              0
```

For those purposes for loop was used, but I have 7000 pos/negWords and 200.000 sentences, so it is neverending...

Please, do you have some better solution for this task. Mainly to have the same result in SentimentScore :-)

I'll appreciate any of your advice or solution. Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Your first step should be to profile your code. Only after you have identified the time-consuming steps you can decide if and how speed can be improved.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should run on subpieces of your data.frame, because list resizing during `lapply` probably generates a huge overhead :

```
ptm = proc.time(); f=lapply(1:100000, function(X){X}); print(proc.time()-ptm)
user        system      elapsed
0.056       0.004       0.061 
ptm = proc.time(); f=lapply(1:1000000, function(X){X}); print(proc.time()-ptm)
user        system      elapsed
1.112       0.004       1.119
```

Here a factor 10 in sequence size yields a factor 21 in computation time. So use small lists, then concatenate them in one big list.

The declaration of a big data.frame does not take long compared to its extension, so you have to declare it and then fill it with your sublists :

```
bbb = data.frame( words=sent[1], user=sent[2], scoreSentence=rep(0, nrow(sent)) )
MAX_SIZE = 10000
for ( ii in 0:(ceiling(nrow(sent)/MAX_SIZE)-1) ) {
   selected_rows = (1 + ii * MAX_SIZE):min( (ii+1)*MAX_SIZE, nrow(sent) )
   bbb[selected_rows, "scoreSentence"] = unlist(lapply(sent$words[selected_rows], scoreSentence))
}
```

`MAX_SIZE` must be big enough because a `for` loop is slower than `lapply` (you want to do as little loop through the `for` as possible) but not too big or the list extension overhead will make the program slower.

**Alternative with parallelisation**

Parallelisation is a good way to make a set of complex calculations faster by running each of them on a different core. In your case we make the calculations complex by sending big chunks of sentences.

With `mclapply` from the `parallel` package, you send each chunk to a different thread each thread is fast because the chunck is not too big. A wrapper for `scoreSentence` that handle a vector is recquired :

```
bbb = data.frame( words=sent[1], user=sent[2], scoreSentence=rep(0, nrow(sent)) )
MAX_SIZE = 10000
mc_list = list()
mc_list[[ceiling(nrow(sent)/MAX_SIZE)]] = 0
for ( ii in 0:(ceiling(nrow(sent)/MAX_SIZE)-1) ) {
    mc_list[[ii+1]] = (1 + ii * MAX_SIZE):min( (ii+1)*MAX_SIZE, nrow(sent) )
}
bbb[,"scoreSentence"] = unlist(mclapply(mc_list, scoreSentenceWrapper))

scoreSentenceWrapper <- function(selected_rows) {
    return(unlist(lapply(sent$words[selected_rows], scoreSentence)))
}
```

Comment: Please, could you help me with that? My r programming skills are at beginner level :-)

Comment: Are you sure in bbb data.frame is sent[1,] or sent[1]?

Comment: In for cycle it counting sentence score 
count <- length(grep(match,sentence)) # count them

Comment: For the `count` line, I mean that grep will return either `1` or `integer(0)`, even if you have more than one match. To get several matches you need `gregexpr`.

Comment: I'm still getting an error and cant figure out, what is bad...

Error: unexpected symbol in:
"  selected_rows = (1 + ii * MAX_SIZE):min(((ii+1)*MAX_SIZE), nrow(sent)
                                          bbb"

Comment: By the way, you could accelerate the `for` loop using `lapply` for `wordsDF` of 1 word. And even for longer ones if they do not overlap (i.e, every set of 2 words has two different words than any other set of 2 words)

Comment: there is another error message:

Error in `*tmp*`[[j]] : recursive indexing failed at level 2

what does it means?

Comment: I corrected some inaccuracies in the `for` loop and the selection of `bbb`'s rows. It works fine for me, and I did not see the `recursive indexing failed` error

Comment: In user and scoreSentence columns are 12 value in 10001 rows. How could I use it form my task, please?

Comment: Dim of bbb data.frame is now correct, but there are only 12 values. Whats that mean?

Comment: What do you mean 12 values ? one line is missing ?

Comment: I mean everywhere is value 12 (in user and scoreSentence)

Comment: I don't reproduce this problem, I get the output you asked for (note that I corrected the `c("user", ...)` which filled the `user` column which you don't want). Did you try with a new R session ?

Comment: I started with new R session and I have this error message:

Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, selected_rows, "scoreSentence", value = NULL) : 
  replacement has length zero

And in scoreSentence column in bbb data.frame there are only zero values.

Comment: Is it with the example data or with your big data.frame ? Because  the example here works fine for me. I think the error is at the line with `unlist(lapply(sent$words[selected_rows], scoreSentence)` which does not produce any result. It means that there are cases where `scoreSentence` does not return anything which is strange. Did you change it ?

Comment: Yes, sorry, I had score in scoreSentence function on the wrong place, before wrong bracket. I run your approach, and it works fine, thank you very much for that. 

And I'd like to ask you, if there is better approach without setting MAX_SIZE. And why do you think the scoreSentence is wrong?

Comment: `count <- length(grep(match,sentence))` will return either 0 or 1 but it seems like you want to be able to find several matches. To do so you need to use `gregexpr` instead of `grep`. Beware that the returned value is not under the same fomat.

Comment: Without using `MAX_SIZE`, the only solution I see is to rewrite lapply so that it initialises the entire list and then adds the values on top of it. You can also look at `mclapply` from the `multicore` package to parallelise the calculations. It can result in a huge speed improvement if you have many cores and does not recquire major modifications of your code.

Comment: Oooh, thats above my knowledge :-) Im not able to implement parallel computing for your proposal. If you could, please, give me a hint.

Comment: count <- length(grep(match,sentence)) with grep it works fine. I've tried some modifications in text with positive and negative multiple terms and works good.

eg. great improvement for that bad product but overall is not good returns -1, which is correct

Comment: Read the documentation, `mclapply` is used exactly like `lapply`. You don't need to build a cluster, R simply forks your process and uses processes communication to gather the results. The parallelisation is done by the OS you don't need to think about it.

Comment: When I tried 
SentimentScore <- unlist(mclapply(sent$words, scoreSentence)) so it takes 37 sec and when I tried 
SentimentScore <- unlist(lapply(sent$words, scoreSentence)) it took 34 sec... but I'm not able to implement mclapply on your approach.

Comment: In fact, your function is too simple, and parallelisation with `mclapply` generates a communication overhead. But it is a simple way to accelerate calculations in some cases without having to refactor the function. If you want to make it effective here, you would have to create a new function to send big chunks of data to each thred, in the same style as I showed here.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. And what about selected_rows variable in bbb[selected_rows, "scoreSentence"] ? Shouldn't it be defined somewhere?

Comment: That resulted into:

Error in `[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, selected_rows, "scoreSentence", value = c(2,  : 
  replacement has 7 rows, data has 1000

Comment: I copy-pasted a bit too fast, the error comes from the `selected_rows` in `bbb[,"scoreSentence"] = unlist(mclapply(mc_list, scoreSentenceWrapper))
` which should no be there. I corrected.

Comment: ok, thanks for that, now it works :-) I compared your approach with SentimentScore <- unlist(lapply(sent$words, scoreSentence)):
For 7 sentences and 7000 words in pos/neg discionary, approach with SentimentScore <- unlist(lapply(sent$words, scoreSentence)) took 2.28 and your with mclapply took 2.32 sec. That seems to be slower approach. The problem is that I have 200.000 sentences and in this case the both approaches are very slow :-( Do you think there is another faster one?

Comment: When you work with so much data, you have to expect some waiting. Also with 7 sentences, there is no decomposition of your data, so the two approach are exactly equivalent the difference you see are just random variations from your machine. You can only compare with a lot of sentences and only a few words in pos/neg.   This it the fastest approach I can give you given what you are trying to achieve. You can also combine them, send very big chunks (as many as the number of cores you want to use) to `mclapply` and then cut it in smaller chunks (to avoid list extension overhead) in the wrapper.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71183/discussion-between-math-and-martin).